# QML and RSA Encryption

Tags: javascript, qt, encryption, qml, rsa

Hi I'm trying to find the best way to generate public and private keys using only js and qml.
This would also involve encrypting and decryption of messages between peer to peer.

I've found this library: 
https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/blob/master/bin/jsencrypt.js

But the problem with using libraries that were designed for a browser is that I never seem to be able to figure them out with the

```
import filePath as JsRASCrypto
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how exactly I could get a library like this one working or any other ways that I could achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Is this to facilitate the secure transfer of data from JavaScript client to server side?

Comment: Uh, just download them? Note that using non-native JavaScript code for crypto is a pretty bad idea; it will be sluggish to say the least and the security is often not guaranteed (wrt side channel attacks, for instance). Using something that uses native libs underneath is probably recommended, *especially* for the extremely slow key generation used for RSA. If you're going for all JS implementations: try Elliptic Curve cryptography (e.g. ECIES). Note that *without trust of the public key* encryption with that public key is not secure against active attacks (who are you encrypting for?).

Comment: How to use libraries for JavaScript isn't much of a cryptography issue, it seems to me. Do you have the same issue with other libs, or is this specific to this one?

Comment: In all honesty I can't remember the errors. I think they were all very similar and knew it was most likely browser specific technology that wasn't compatible with qml. And it doesn't necessarily have to be js as far as the lib itsself. it just would have been nice.
Im very much up for suggestions on this.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I'm wanting to do this because I need to send secured packages from a to be with the traditional rsa encryption/signing etc.
But I'm far from an expert so I don't know how this works or the best way. I just keep seeing a lot of this around when researching how to send secured messages etc

Comment: Some JS libs might be designed to be used from a specific environment. It would take a JS library to be designed to be env agnostic in order to work with QML. This one looks like it might be designed to work with HTML, i.e. browsers.

Comment: Why can't you just use HTTPS?

Comment: why cant you use  a Qt AES implementation for  Qt C++ and just expose it to QML? https://github.com/bricke/Qt-AES   and  qRegisterType<>() or use Q_INVOKABLE

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. But i think @mike510a's comment is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly easy to implement this by downloading
https://github.com/bricke/Qt-AES
and adding the files qaesencryption.h  and qaesencryption.cpp into your project, then create a controller class which can access the QAESEncryption methods and make a few Q_INVOKABLE typed methods to handle the encryption then expose the AES controller class to your QML engine

no problem

### aes.h

```
#ifndef AES_H
#define AES_H

#include <QObject>

class AES : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AES(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant encrypt(QString plainText, QString key);


    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant decrypt(QString encodedText, QString key);
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // AES_H
```

---

### aes.cpp

```
#include "aes.h"
#include "qaesencryption.h"

AES::AES(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QVariant AES::encrypt(QString plainText, QString key)
{
  QAESEncryption encryption(QAESEncryption::AES_128, QAESEncryption::ECB);
  QByteArray encodedText = encryption.encode(plainText, key);
  return QVariant::fromValue(encodedText);
}

QVariant AES::decrypt(QString encodedText, QString key)
{
  QAESEncryption encryption(QAESEncryption::AES_128, QAESEncryption::ECB);
  QByteArray decodedText = encryption.decode(encodedText, key);
  return QVariant::fromValue(decodedText);
}
```

----

### main.cpp

Heres where to register QML type

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "aes.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    
    
    /* register AES class into QML */
    qmlRegisterType<AES>("com.myapp.demo", 1, 0, "AES");
    
    
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

----

main.qml
--

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import com.myapp.demo 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    /* make an instance of AES */
    AES {
        id: aes
    }
   
    /* call invokable method */
    Component.onCompleted: {
        alert(aes.encrypt("testing encryption", "secretKey"))
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone out there figure things out

Comment: Hi @mike510a this is exactly what i'm looking for, could I just ask - in your `aes.h` your third line is just `#include` however whenever I implement this i receive an error `expected "file name" or <file name>` what could I do to rectify this?

Comment: @Ldweller I have fixed the formatting issue on the aes.h file, it was the result of the < > symbols making the browser think that theres HTML there which stackoverflow filtered out